# Outlook API, Get Multiple Messages from Message-IDs

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using the Microsoft Graph API. 
I would like to know if it's possible for a given user to get a list of messages (Mails) from a list of Message ID ?

I have a List of Messages ID; Can I, using the Microsoft Graph API get the list of corresponding messages ? (I don't want to Use the Batch, because it's limited to 20 results).

There is this endpoint: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#
That allows to get one message by giving its ID. 
What I need is to get multiple messages (like 500) by giving the IDs.
Is that possible ?

Comment: You could open a feature request on [https://officespdev.uservoice.com/](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) maybe it catches the Graph dev-teams attention

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in the Graph API.
The only operation that returns a List of messages will return a list of messages of a specified Folder

```
GET /me/messages                      (returns all messages of the mailbox)
GET /me/mailFolders/{id}/messages     (returns all messages of a folder inside the mailbox)
```

from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_messages

Your only option is to use a batch request.